# Runtime Error integrating a component lib that uses @vue/composition-api: 'You must use this function within the "setup()" method'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli, vue-composition-api, vue-cli-4

Any help with the following problem would be greatly appreciated!

### Situation:

My [project](http://github.com/tholst/vue-composition-api-comp-lib) contains **two packages**:

1. **child-component-lib**

   - contains a single view `About.vue` written in composition-API-style (with vue2 helper libraries `@vue/composition-api` and `vuex-composition-helpers`)
   - exports a single `RouteConfig`
   - build as a lib

   **`views/About.vue` (child)**

   ```html
   <template>
     <div class="about">
       <h1>This is an about page (as component lib)</h1>
     </div>
   </template>

   <script>
   import { defineComponent } from "@vue/composition-api";
   import { createNamespacedHelpers } from "vuex-composition-helpers";

   export default defineComponent({
     components: {},
     setup(_, { root }) {
       const { useGetters, useActions } = createNamespacedHelpers("account"); // error thrown here!
     }
   });
   </script>
   ```

   **`router/index.ts` (child)**

   ```js
   export const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [{
       path: "/",
       name: "About",
       component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/About.vue")
   }];
   ```

   **`lib.ts` (child)**

   ```js
   export const routes = require("@/router").routes;
   ```

   **`package.json` (child)**

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "build": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name child-component-lib src/lib.ts"
   ...
   ```

---

2. **parent-app**

   - imports the route from `child-component-lib` into its router
   - contains a simple view that displays one line of text and a `<router-view />`

   **`package.json` (parent)**

   ```json
   "dependencies": {
       "@tholst/child-component-lib": "file:../child-component-lib",
   ```

   **`router/index.ts` (parent)**

   ```js
   import { routes as childComponentRoutes } from "@tholst/child-component-lib";

   const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [...childComponentRoutes];
   const router = new VueRouter({routes});    
   export default router;
   ```

   **`App.vue` (parent)**

   ```html
   <template>
     <div id="app">
       <Home />
       <router-view />
     </div>
   </template>

   <script>
   import { defineComponent } from "@vue/composition-api";
   import Home from "@/views/Home.vue";

   export default defineComponent({
     components: {
       Home
     },
     setup(_, { root }) {
       ...
     }
   });
   </script>
   ```

#### Expected behavior

It works without problems.

#### Actual behavior

I see an error output in the console. `[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "Error: You must use this function within the "setup()" method, or insert the store as first argument."` The error message is misleading, because the error is actually thrown inside `setup()` method. It can be traced back to `getCurrentInstance()` returning `undefined` (inside `@vue/composition-api`).

---

### Investigation:

- It turns out that the **error disappears when** I include the same `About.vue` in the parent-app itself (just switch the route, to try it out), i.e., it works when **we avoid the import from the built library**.
- So it **looks like it's a problem with the build setup**
  (one of `vue.config.js`, `webpack`, `babel`, `typescript`, ...)

---

### Reproduce the error:

#### 1. Clone, install, run

```sh
git clone git@github.com:tholst/vue-composition-api-comp-lib.git && cd vue-composition-api-comp-lib/child-component-lib && npm install && npm run build && cd ../parent-app/ && npm install && npm run serve
```

or one by one

```sh
git clone git@github.com:tholst/vue-composition-api-comp-lib.git
cd vue-composition-api-comp-lib/child-component-lib
npm install
npm run build
cd ../parent-app/
npm install
npm run serve
```

#### 2. Open Browser

- Go to http://localhost:8080/

#### 3. Open Dev Tools to See Error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "Error: You must use this function within the "setup()" method, or insert the store as first argument."

found in

---> <Anonymous>
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

### Error Screenshot

[image: Error in console]

### Environment Info:

```
Node: 14.2.0
npm: 6.14.8
Chrome: 86.0.4240.198

npmPackages:
    @vue/babel-sugar-composition-api-inject-h:  1.2.1 
    @vue/babel-sugar-composition-api-render-instance:  1.2.4 
    ...    
    @vue/cli-overlay:  4.5.8 
    @vue/cli-plugin-babel: 4.5.8 
    @vue/cli-plugin-router: 4.5.8 
    @vue/cli-plugin-typescript: 4.5.8 
    @vue/cli-plugin-vuex:4.5.8 
    @vue/cli-service: 4.5.8 
    @vue/cli-shared-utils:  4.5.8 
    @vue/component-compiler-utils:  3.2.0 
    @vue/composition-api: 1.0.0-beta.19 
    @vue/preload-webpack-plugin:  1.1.2 
    typescript: 3.9.7 
    vue: 2.6.12 
    vue-loader:  15.9.5 (16.0.0-rc.1)
    vue-router: 3.4.9
    vue-template-compiler: 2.6.12 
    vue-template-es2015-compiler:  1.9.1 
    vuex: 3.5.1 
    vuex-composition-helpers: 1.0.21 

npmGlobalPackages:
    @vue/cli: 4.5.8
```

Answer (score 3):

I finally understood what the problems were. First, there was the actual problem. Second, there was a problem in the local development setup that made solutions to the actual problem look like they were not working.

### The Actual Problem + Solution

The child-component-lib was bundling their own versions of the npm packages `@vue/composition-api` and `vuex-composition-helpers`. This had the following effect: When I was running the parent-app there were actually *two instances* of those libraries and the vue component from the child-component-lib was accessing the wrong object that had not been properly initialized.

The solution was to prevent the bundling of those libraries in the child-component-lib, by

1. making them `devDependencies` and `peerDependencies`.
2. instructing webpack not to bundle them on `npm run build`.

   **`package.json`**

   ```json
   "dependencies": {
       ...
   },
   "devDependencies": {
       "@vue/composition-api": "^1.0.0-beta.19",
       "vuex-composition-helpers": "^1.0.21",
       ...
   },
   "peerDependencies": {
       "@vue/composition-api": "^1.0.0-beta.19",
       "vuex-composition-helpers": "^1.0.21"
   },
   ```

   **`vue.config.js`**

   ```js
   configureWebpack: {
       externals: {
           "@vue/composition-api": "@vue/composition-api",
           "vuex-composition-helpers": "vuex-composition-helpers"
       },
       ...
   }
   ```

### The Tricky Problem that Made Things Difficult

I was trying to fix this problem locally, without actually publishing the package. And it seemed to work, because I was seeing the same problem locally that I also saw in the published packages.

I did local development by directly linking the parent-app and child-component-libs. I tried both

1. a **direct folder dependency**

   **`package.json`**

   ```json
   "dependencies": {
       "@tholst/child-component-lib": "file:../child-component-lib",
   },
   ```
2. **`npm link`**

   ```sh
   cd child-component-lib
   npm link
   cd ../parent-app
   npm link @tholst/child-component-lib
   ```

Both approaches have the effect that they actually import (=symlink to) the child-component-lib's folder **with all files and folders** (instead of only the files that would be published in the npm package).

And that meant the following: **Even though** I had excluded the two composition-API libs from the bundle and made them dev/peer dependencies (see solution to actual problem), they **were still installed** and present in the child-component-lib's `node_modules`. And that `node_modules` folder was symlinked into the parent-app package. And in this way the child-component-lib still had access to their own copy of the libraries that we wanted to exclude from the build (see actual problem). And I was still seeing the error as before.

And this way my local development approach obscured the fact that the solution to the actual problem *was actually working*.

Comment: I wish to have saw your post before , got the exact same problem and i struggled so much to find the solution !

Comment: @JoelPintoRibeiro Yes, it took me days of struggle as well!